# How to throw an error in Bash?

Tags: bash

How do I throw an error in bash to get in my *catch* clause (I'm not sure what this expression is actually called)

```
{
  # ...
  if [ "$status" -ne "200" ]
    # throw error
  fi
} || {
  # on error / where I want to get if status != 200
}
```

I know I just could use a function but this case made me curious if it would be possible to do this

Comment: the `||`d block will work, just add `echo "err msg" ; exit 1;`? OR use more traditional `if cond ; then echo OK ; else echo ERR ; fi` ? OR you need to give a more detailed (but small) use case. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter why as comment? exit will not end in the *catch clause* tho, I already tried that

Comment: Yes, why not just use `if` and `else`? This is strange syntax to try for.

Comment: see my revised comment above. Sorry, I'm going out for a while. I'm sure others will pile on ;-) Good luck.

Comment: If that `if` construct is the last in the block, then `[ "$status" -eq "200" ]` is enough, no need for `if`. Otherwise, there's no way to achieve what you want, unless you set up a `trap`, which might or might not suit your situation. Alternatively, you can use a parameter, say `errored`, and test `errored` at the end of the block.

Comment: @miken32 because in `# ...` are a lot of commands which can fail and need to be catched - which will execute the same operations as in my if clause. So I would need to use a function. The question is more about if it's possible than if it's useful

Comment: Then you should be able place those commands in an actual function, and use a standard `if [ myfunction ]; then ...; else ...; fi` As mentioned above, just use `exit 1` to indicate an error condition.

Comment: @miken32 I've explained that already in my question

Comment: @Brettetete I think my solution with an error variable is what you might prefer then. Initialize error at 0; at every location where you want to "throw" an error; set the error variable to a non-zero value of your choice; and test at the end whether the value is non-zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do something similar:

**use subshells** (might not be the best solution if you want to set parameters etc...)

```
(
if [[ "$status" -ne "200" ]]
then
    exit 1
fi 
) || (
  # on error / where I want to get if status != 200
  echo "error thrown"
)
```

**use an intermediate *error* variable** (you can catch multiple errors by setting different numbers. Also: less indentation depth)

```
if [[ "$status" -ne "200" ]]
then
    error=1
fi

if [ $error != 0 ]
then
    echo "error $error thrown"
fi
```

**use immediately the exit value of your test** (note that I changed `-ne` to `-eq`)

```
[[ "$status" -eq "200" ]] || echo "error thrown"
```

Comment: I personally usually opt for something like your `$error`. Downside is you could have a bunch of stuff between your failure and your final error code checking, which you would like to skip on error. Now they need to have one extra indentation level, when logically they probably should be top level.

Comment: I know , but I have the impression he wants to do other stuff before checking whether the error was thrown...

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is with just exit as shellter mentions, but you have to create a subshell for that work (which exists on the exit). To do this, replace the curly brackets with parentheses.

The code will be

```
(
 # ...
 if [ "$status" -ne "200" ]
    exit 1
 fi
) || {
   # on error / where I want to get if status != 200
}
```

Comment: Creating a subshell is not viable in many cases (e.g., you can't set any parameter), so definitely not recommended.

Comment: @4ae1e1, the closest thing in bash to do that is to do just this. You can use different exit codes if you want to differentiate between different "exceptions"

Comment: No, this is clearly not the "closest thing in bash". There's the `trap` builtin.

Comment: @4ae1e1, I agree `trap` is more idiomatic, but it is equivalent to having a single global try-catch block. This version lets you have multiple nested ones. Also, `trap` does not let you resume execution at a latter point.

Comment: @4ae1e1, as for creating subshells not being recommended, I do not agree. You can easily `export` variables to them, and here it gives you functionality you can not get without them.

Comment: Did you listen to what I said? You can't **SET** parameters in the subshell, whether you export or not. As for resuming execution, `trap` can be inside a function. Apparently I meant to wrap this up in a function, which I pointed out as a downside in another comment, by the way.

Comment: @4ae1e1, I misunderstood you (parameters made think of something you are passing in, not returning out). I'd still argue that this is the closest to exception like semantics in bash if you want to be able to nest them. Overall though, I agree with you that in most circumstances this is not what you'd want to do.

Comment: Ah crap, I think I made a mistake about `trap`. Was thinking about Zsh trap, which when wrapped in a function can be triggered at function return... Sorry.

Comment: @4ae1e1, no worries. Did not now zsh could do that, that's pretty interesting.

Comment: @toth: Bash speak has its quirks: "parameter" is the _umbrella term_ for (a) arguments (`$1`, ... - "positional parameters"), (b) special variables (e.g., `$$` - "special parameters") and (c) variables ("named parameters"). Perhaps you could explicitly state not being able to set variables (and affect the current shell's environment in general) as a limitation of your answer.

Comment: @mklement0 Manipulations on positional parameters also can't be propagated to parent shell. I guess I shouldn't include special parameters though, because it's kind of silly to talk about "setting" `$?` and such.

Answer (score 0):

The return code for the braces is the return code of the last statement executed in the braces.  So, here is one method that uses the shell-builtin `false`:

```
{
  # ...
  if [ "$status" -ne "200" ]; then
    false # throws "error" (return code=1)
  fi
} || {
  echo "Caught error" # on error / where I want to get if status != 200
}
```

In this particular case, the `if` statement is superfluous.  The test statement, `[ "$status" -ne "200" ]`, throws the exit code that you need:

```
{
  # ...
  ! [ "$status" -ne "200" ]
} || {
  echo "Caught error" # on error / where I want to get if status != 200
}
```

Comment: This will not work if there is code after the if statement, the return status will be the return status of last command. A better way is to use a subshell.

Comment: @toth It's sort of a better way, until you need to set a parameter. Don't use a subshell until it's necessary. As I said above, use `trap` if you really need to emulate a throw/catch pair (downside is you need to wrap your stuff in a function).

Comment: @John1024, what I meant is that usually with "exceptions" you can throw them anywhere, not just the last line of a function. The subshell + exit solution lets you do this, `false` does not.